# How should I Integrate a List View into Google Maps using Knockout

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I am still a novice when it comes to framework integration, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to make a list of different predetermined places on a map and place markers for each different location. The problem that I seem to be having is with applying the bindings for Knockout. The map worked and placed all of the markers before I encapsulated it in the appViewModel() function and tried to apply the bindings. I am at a loss as to why this is not working.

As it stands now, the map just shows up blank, and I can't seem to find the cause for that.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .results {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          position: absolute;
          top: 25px;
          right: 10px;
          background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
          width: 25%;
          max-height: 90%;
          border: 1px solid gray;
      }
      #results-list {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 450px;
      }

      #results-list li {
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        padding: 0 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #results-list li h4 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        color: #2A6496;
      }

      #results-list .address {
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.4;
        margin-top: 4px;
      }

      #results-list p {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"><!-- Map goes here! --></div>

    <div class="results">
      <div>
        <ul id="results-list" data-bind="foreach: markers">
          <li>
            <h4 data-bind="text: name"></h4>
            <p class="address" data-bind="text: address"></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my JavaScrpit:

```
function appViewModel() {

var self = this;

self.markers = ko.observableArray([
        {name: 'Sammy’s Neighborhood Pub', lat: 35.2414025, lon: -81.03791130000002, address: '25 S Main St, Belmont, NC 28012'},
        {name: 'River’s Edge Bar & Grill', lat: 35.2725889, lon: -81.00531569999998, address: '5000 Whitewater Center Pkwy, Charlotte, NC 28214'},
        {name: 'Sports Page Food & Spirits', lat: 35.3038033, lon: -80.9366445, address: '8400 Bellhaven Blvd # H, Charlotte, NC 28216'},
        {name: 'Planet Fitness - Charlotte', lat: 35.2451844, lon: -80.89506440000002, address: '3301 Freedom Dr #600, Charlotte, NC 28208'},
        {name: 'CrossFit SouthEnd', lat: 35.222195, lon: -80.855435, address: '1115 S Mint St, Charlotte, NC 28203'},
        {name: 'ULTIMATE GYM', lat: 35.2458253, lon: -80.7826842, address: '1224 Commercial Ave, Charlotte, NC 28205'}
    ]);

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Sammy’s Neighborhood Pub</h3>' +
        '<p>25 S Main St, Belmont, NC 28012</p>' + '</div>'],

        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>River’s Edge Bar & Grill</h3>' +
        '<p>5000 Whitewater Center Pkwy, Charlotte, NC 28214</p>' + '</div>'],

        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Sports Page Food & Spirits</h3>' +
        '<p>8400 Bellhaven Blvd # H, Charlotte, NC 28216</p>' + '</div>'],

        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Planet Fitness - Charlotte</h3>' +
        '<p>3301 Freedom Dr #600, Charlotte, NC 28208</p>' + '</div>'],

        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>CrossFit SouthEnd</h3>' +
        '<p>1115 S Mint St, Charlotte, NC 28203</p>' + '</div>'],

        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>ULTIMATE GYM</h3>' +
        '<p>1224 Commercial Ave, Charlotte, NC 28205</p>' + '</div>']
    ];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    for( i = 0; i < markers().length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(self.markers()[i].lat, self.markers()[i].lon);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: self.markers()[i].name
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }


    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(12);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}

 initialize();
}


ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
```

I also noticed that, in the console, it doesn't recognize initialize() as a function, and I'm not sure why that's the case either.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Here is my GitHub repository for the app: https://github.com/Kalypzoid/Google-Maps-Project

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data critical for the understanding of your question. Please remember to provide all necessary data (code, configuration data, exception name ...) in **the question itself**. If the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning!

Comment: Your question is a bit too general, too.  You'll have better luck if you ask a specific question.  Look here for some tips:  http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.   Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you for your time and quick responses guys! I have added the relevant code, and I tried to ask a more direct question.